# 20m Old Baby Is Insanely Cranky + Clingy + Not Leaving Her Mom, We Are At Our Wits End!

Tags: breastfeeding, crying, sickness

My first question here, and here's the situation:

20 month old baby girl. Had a bout of the rainy stomach bug 5 days ago, she was down with a bad fever for 2 days, recovered from the fever on the 3rd day.

But from the last 3 days:

1. She has eaten like 5 tbsps of rice. That's it.
2. She's still
   breast fed, so she's feeding almost every other hour (obviously she's
   hungry?)
3. She's become insanely cranky and clingy, not leaving her
   mother even for a second.
4. Interact with her with anything,
   **ANYTHING**, and she starts crying inconsolably. And we have tried like
   everything, the only response is crying + submissive behavior.
5. She's not in pain or discomfort, when we put some of her favorite
   videos, she will watch them... sitting in our lap of course! She does have a little runny nose, but not like a full blown cold.

We are at our wits end now, how do we resolve this? Is this a phase? She was never like this, always quite independent at home.

How many days can she go without any food? And we have tried ALL her favorite foods, she just keeps saying no to every one of them, as if we are offering her poison, and oh yes, she also starts crying then too!

Help please, this is our second child, and though we are "experienced", this is something we are not able to decipher...

Answer (score 6):

This does not, on the face of it, sound terribly unusual.

- She has probably not fully recovered yet. If she is still feeling ill, it makes sense for her to be cranky. Wouldn't you be?
- If she is breastfeeding regularly, she may not need more food. Even if she normally eats other food, during stomach problems hunger is often reduced, so she may not want more. Not eating for a while is generally not so problematic, the important thing is to drink enough.

However, if you have even the slighest worries about her state, **take her to a doctor**. In your case there is ample reason to do so, so take her to a doctor as soon as possible to have her checked out.

From what you describe, I don't think she is in a critical situation, but there is no point in taking a chance. Just **have her checked out**, and you will hopefully all sleep better soon.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. No, she's no dehydrated, she's urinating fairly regularly, with a clear color.

She just started "looking" at food yesterday and ate 3 morsels, lol! :D

But again she's lethargic, sleeping a lot today morning. :(

The only reason we're not too keen to go to her Doctor is it's the rainy season in India right now, and clinics are flooded with very sick babies. 

So we just don't want her to catch something new there, given her possibly weak/stressed immune system right now.

I guess we'll see how the weekend goes, and decide accordingly...

Comment: Agree with sleske. @Amod, good to hear that your daughter is eating again.